# @ Object.convertDocToObj TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of null

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

I'm having a problem, and I don't really know how to fix this. Been at this for a while now.
I get this typeError with mongoDB:

```
    utils\db.js (38:16) @ Object.convertDocToObj
    TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of null
      36 | 
      37 | function convertDocToObj(doc) {
    > 38 |   doc._id = doc._id.toString();
         |                ^
      39 |   doc.createdAt = doc.createdAt.toString();
      40 |   doc.updatedAt = doc.updatedAt.toString();
      41 |   return doc;
```

This my `db.js`

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const connection = {};

async function connect() {
  if (connection.isConnected) {
    console.log('already connected');
    return;
  }
  if (mongoose.connections.length > 0) {
    connection.isConnected = mongoose.connections[0].readyState;
    if (connection.isConnected === 1) {
      console.log('use previous connection');
      return;
    }
    await mongoose.disconnect();
  }
  const db = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  });
  console.log('new connection');
  connection.isConnected = db.connections[0].readyState;
}

async function disconnect() {
  if (connection.isConnected) {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
      await mongoose.disconnect();
      connection.isConnected = false;
    } else {
      console.log('not disconnected');
    }
  }
}

function convertDocToObj(doc) {
  doc._id = doc._id.toString();
  doc.createdAt = doc.createdAt.toString();
  doc.updatedAt = doc.updatedAt.toString();
  return doc;
}

const db = { connect, disconnect, convertDocToObj };
export default db;
```

This is my `[slug].js`

```
import React from 'react'
import useStyles from '../../utils/styles'
import NextLink from 'next/link'
import { Link, Grid, List, ListItem, Typography, Card, Button } from '@material-ui/core'
import Image from 'next/image'
import Layout from '../../components/Layout'
import Product from '../../models/Product'
import db from '../../utils/db';

export default function ProductScreen(props) {
    const { product } = props
    const classes = useStyles()
    if(!product) {
        return <div>Product Not Found</div>
    }
    return (
        <Layout title={product.name} description={product.description}>
            <div className={classes.section}>
                <NextLink href="/" passHref>
                    <Link>Back to Products</Link>
                </NextLink>
            </div>
            <Grid container spacing={1}>
                <Grid item md={6} xs={12}>
                    <Image src={product.image} alt={product.name} width={640} height={640} layout="responsive"/>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item md={3} xs={12}>
                    <List>
                        <ListItem>
                            <Typography component="h1" variant='h1'>
                                {product.name}
                            </Typography>
                        </ListItem>
                        <ListItem>
                            <Typography>
                                Category: {product.category}
                            </Typography>
                        </ListItem>
                        <ListItem>
                            <Typography>
                                Brand: {product.brand}
                            </Typography>
                        </ListItem>
                        <ListItem> 
                            <Typography>
                                Rating: {product.rating} stars ({product.numReviews} reviews)
                            </Typography>
                        </ListItem>
                        <ListItem>
                            <Typography>Description: {product.description}</Typography>
                        </ListItem>
                    </List>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item md={3} xs={12}>
                    <Card>
                        <List>
                            <ListItem>
                                <Grid container>
                                    <Grid item xs={6}><Typography>Price</Typography></Grid>
                                    <Grid item xs={6}><Typography>${product.price}</Typography></Grid>
                                </Grid>
                            </ListItem>
                            <ListItem>
                                <Grid container>
                                    <Grid item xs={6}><Typography>Status</Typography></Grid>
                                    <Grid item xs={6}><Typography>{product.countInStock>0?'In stock':'Unavailable'}</Typography></Grid>
                                </Grid>
                            </ListItem>
                            <ListItem>
                                <Button fullWidth variant="contained" color='primary'>
                                    Add to Cart
                                </Button>
                            </ListItem>
                        </List>
                    </Card>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Layout>
    )
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    const { params } = context;
    const { slug } = params;
  
    await db.connect();
    const product = await Product.findOne({ slug }).lean();
    await db.disconnect();
    return {
      props: {
        product: db.convertDocToObj(product),
      },
    };
  }
```

This is my `index.js`

```
import Layout from '../components/Layout'
import NextLink from 'next/link'
import { Grid, Card, CardActionArea, CardMedia, CardContent, CardActions, Button, Typography } from '@material-ui/core';
import Product from '../models/Product';
import db from '../utils/db';

export default function Home(props) {
  const {products} = props;
  return (
    <Layout>
      <div>
        <h1>Products</h1>
        <Grid container spacing={3}>
          {data.products.map((product) => (
            <Grid item md={4} key={product.name}>
              <Card>
                <NextLink href={`/product/${product.slug}`} passHref>
                <CardActionArea>
                  <CardMedia 
                    component="img"
                    image={product.image}
                    title={product.name}
                    ></CardMedia>
                    <CardContent>
                      <Typography>
                        {product.name}
                      </Typography>
                    </CardContent>
                </CardActionArea>
                </NextLink>
                <CardActions>
                  <Typography>${product.price}</Typography>
                  <Button size='small' color='primary'>
                    Add to Cart...
                  </Button>
                </CardActions>
              </Card>
            </Grid>
          ))}
        </Grid>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  await db.connect();
  const products = await Product.find({}).lean();
  await db.disconnect()
  return {
    props: {
      products: products.map(db.convertDocToObj),
    },
  }
}
```

And here is my `index.js` api

```
import nc from 'next-connect';
import Product from '../../../models/Product';
import db from '../../../utils/db';
    
const handler = nc();
    
handler.get(async (req, res) => {
    await db.connect();
    const products = await Product.find({});
    await db.disconnect();
    res.send(products);
});
    
export default handler;
```

Comment: Either make sure the variable passed to `db.convertDocToObj` isn't null/undefined, or handle that case inside the `convertDocToObj` function itself.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `lean()` method, you won't have the `id`. The `lean()` method disables the hydration process which is converting the original result from POJO to Mongoose document. This means that the results you have are in POJO which doesn't include the `id`.

Try removing the `lean()` and see if that helps.

Also, you can use [mongoose-lean-id](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-lean-id) module to include the `id` in the results while using `lean()`, I personally never used it.